# Type Mismatch error in function using DateValue(), how to troubleshoot?

Tags: vba, excel

Warning: I'm a noob.

I've written a Sub to find cells with red text and alter them.

@ThinkerIV gave me a great function to put in a cell and drag the formula out into adjoining cells, but that won't work due to the number of sheets to work on.
So I wrote my Sub, calling his function (see code below). I passed it a Range of one cell, so it seems to me it should work?

But, it keeps throwing out Type Mismatch (run-time error code 13) on the line where the function calls the DateValue()! The passed range shows a value of 1 (which is the number in the cell it refers to) when I hover over it in the editor, but I don'rt know if that's the cell's contents or some other value 1 being shown.

So, I really don't know how to find out exactly why this is happening. Is it that the range I passed is somehow not the right kind? Please inform me of why this code won't work!

I tried to change that line to the comment line below it (and a couple other blind-guess changes), but that has the same error.

Thanks in advance!

```
    Sub redTextToRealDates()

    Dim dateTemp As Date
    Dim redCell As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim thisSheetsRange As Range
    Dim busyCell As Range
    Dim redTextCells As Range
    Set thisSheetsRange = ActiveSheet.usedRange

    'Build a range containing all the cells in a sheet containing red text.
    '  well... all cells formatted to HAVE red text, anyway.
    '  Anyone want to tell me how to write this to skip empty cells?
    '  Because I don't need to grab empty cells into this range...

    For Each busyCell In thisSheetsRange
        If (busyCell.Font.ColorIndex()) = 3 Then
            If redTextCells Is Nothing Then
            Set redTextCells = busyCell
            Else: Set redTextCells = Union(redTextCells, busyCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next busyCell

    'Change unknown format cells to date cells populated with concantenated
    'string of original contents and the active sheet's name.

    For Each foundCell In redTextCells
        foundCell.NumberFormat = "@"
        foundCell = GetConcantDate(foundCell)

    Next foundCell

    redTextCells.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
    On Error Resume Next


    End Sub


    Function GetConcantDate(rng As Range) As Date
        'Original code supplied by ThinkerIV on StackOverflow.com
        Dim dtTemp As Date
        dtTemp = DateValue(rng.Range("A1").Value & " " & rng.Parent.Name)
         'dateTemp = DateValue(foundCell.Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Name)
        GetConcantDate = dtTemp
    End Function
```

EDIT
 I cant post my own answer yet, so I am adding this solution:

When feeding data to Format(), the contents of the first cell formatted for red were NOT in text form. I had not put in place any way to ensure that I passed the proper data type. So, the line to format the cell as text (foundCell.NumberFormat = "@") before passing it to the function is what fixed it.

The solution was actually already written when I copy/pasted the code into the question - I just wasn't aware that it had fixed it because of another error on a different Sub. (I'm a noob and was confused dealing with multiple errors in multiple subs) I thought I had tried it again with that new line, but HADN'T, so still thought it was not working.

Thanks to all who helped. I feel a bit of a fool now, having found it like that. Hope you forgive me for my rookie flubber - too many Subs and Functions in a huge list in the editor and I got 'dizzy'... At least I can post a solution in case some other noob needs it!

Comment: `DateValue` throws error 13 if the passed string does not represent a date. `Debug.? rng.Range("A1").Value & " " & rng.Parent.Name`.

Comment: In your GetConcantDate function should't you be using rng.cells(1).value rather than rng.Range("A1").value?

Comment: @nemmy The are both valid and give the same result.

Comment: Put this line in before the dtTemp=DateValue line:

debug.print rngtmp.cells(1).value & " " & rng.parent.name

And report back what you see in the debug window when your GetConcantDate is called.

Comment: What is the sheet name. Perhaps the value of A1 and the sheet name cannot be converted to a date.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think there are two things here. Firstly, the DateValue function takes a string representation of a date, e.g. "01/01/2013", when you pass through an excel date from a range, you are passing through a number, like 41275. This throws the run time error 13.

However, if you already have a date, why bother converting it? You seem to want all red cells to be converted to a date + the sheetname. To do this you'll have to have strings e.g. "01/01/2013 Sheet1", so you couldn't use DateValue here. Instead perhaps try something like this:

```
Public Function GetConcatDate(rng As Range) As String
    Dim dtTemp As String
    dtTemp = Format(rng.Range("A1").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " " & rng.Parent.Name
    GetConcatDate = dtTemp
End Function
```

Comment: The date row was just the day number. Eg: "1" or "28". They were in cells formatted as "General" or as "Text" - I don't know why it was done like this, I didn't make the sheet. So I assumed it was strings being passed into the function. See answer below.